# Clipping tensor data to a bounding volume

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, bounding-volume

I have 2 questions about tensorflow 2.0, with the focus on how tensorflow handles combined conditional tests in it's operations graph.

The task: cut up a volume of data points into blocks, and store the *indices* to the samples that belong to the volume (not the samples themselves).

My initial approach: loop all elements and collect the indices of the data points that are inside the 'bounding volume'. This was pretty slow, no matter how I reordered the compares on the coordinates.

```py
    # X.shape == [elements,features]
    # xmin.shape == xmax.shape == [features]

    def getIndices(X, xmin, xmax):
        i = 0
        indices = tf.zero(shape[0], dtype = tf.int32)
        for x in X:
            if (x[0] > xmin[0]):
                if (x[1] > xmin[1]):
                    if (x[2] <= xmax[2]):

                        # ...and so on...

                        indices = tf.concat([indices, i], axis = 0)
            i = i + 1
        return indices
```

I then came up with the idea to produce boolean tensors and logically 'and' them to get the `indices` of the elements I need. A whole lot faster, as shown in the next sample:

```py
    # X.shape == [elements,features]
    # xmin.shape == xmax.shape == [features]

    def getIndices(X, xmin, xmax):
        # example of 3 different conditions to clip to (a part of) the bounding volume 
        # X is the data and xmin and xmax are tensors containing the bounding volume

        c0 = (X[:,0] >   xmin[0])
        c1 = (X[:,1] >   xmin[1]) # processing all elements
        c2 = (X[:,2] <=  xmax[2]) # idem

        # ... there could be many more conditions, you get the idea..

        indices = tf.where(tf.math.logical_and(c1, tf.math.logical_and(c2, c3) )

        return indices

    #    ...

    indices = getIndices(X, xmin, xmax)
    trimmedX = tf.gather(X, indices)
```

This code produces the *correct* result, but I wonder if it is *optimal*.

**The first question is about scheduling:**

> Will the tensorflow graph that holds the operations cull (blocks of)
> conditional tests if it knows some (blocks of) elements already tested
> `False`. Because of the `logical_and` combining the logical
> conditionals, no subsequent conditional test on these elements will
> ever yield a `True`.

Indeed, in the above example `c1` and `c2` are asking questions on elements that may `c0` already excluded from the set. Especially when you have a high number of elements to test, this could be a waste of time, even on parallel hardware platforms

So, what if we cascade the tests based on the results of a previous test?  Although it seems like a solved problem, this solution is incorrect, because the final `indices` tensor will refer to a subset `_X`, not to the total set `X`:

```py
    # X.shape == [elements,features]
    # xmin.shape == xmax.shape == [features]

    def getIndices(X, xmin, xmax):
        c0 = (X[:,0] >   xmin[0])
        indices = tf.where(c0)
        _X = tf.gather(X, indices)

        c1 = (_X[:,1] >   xmin[1]) # processing only trimmed elements
        indices = tf.where(c1)
        _X = tf.gather(_X, indices)

        c2 = (_X[:,2] <=  xmax[2]) # idem
        indices = tf.where(c2)
        return indices

    ...
    indices = getIndices(X, xmin, xmax)
    trimmedX = tf.gather(X, indices)  # fails: indices refer to a trimmed subset, not X
```

I could of course 'solve' this by simply expanding `X`, so that each element also includes the index of itself in the original list, and then proceed as before.

**So my second question is about functionality:**

> Does tf have a method to make the GPU/tensor infrastructure provide
> the bookkeeping without spending memory / time on this seemingly
> simple problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could provide a solution, but in all honesty, I read this three times and can't understand what you're actually trying to do

Comment: Ok, maybe I should mention that X has shape [elements,features], and xmin and xmax have both shape [features]. What I'm trying to do is get the indices of the elements that lie inside the bounding volume, where the volume is defined by limits (min and/or max) on certain feature values.

Comment: I updated the question with a bit more structure and rephrased it a bit. I'm not a native English speaker so I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

This will return all indices larger than `minimum` and less than `maximum` when both of these have the same number of features as `X`

```
import tensorflow as tf

minimum = tf.random.uniform((1, 5), 0., 0.5)
maximum = tf.random.uniform((1, 5), 0.5, 1.)

x = tf.random.uniform((10, 5))

indices = tf.where(
    tf.logical_and(
        tf.greater(x, minimum),
        tf.less(x, maximum)
        )
    )
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(22, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[0, 3],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 0],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 3],
       [6, 2],
       [6, 3],
       [7, 1],
       [7, 4],
       [8, 2],
       [8, 3],
       [8, 4],
       [9, 1],
       [9, 3],
       [9, 4]], dtype=int64)>
```

Comment: Your solution is similar to the second listing of my OP. And that works! But those 2 conditional test are combined with `logical_and` and  live in a graph, right, so let's suppose you expect that most consecutive elements in `tf.greater(x, minimum)` will return `False`, and similarly for the other condition, (for different elements). Will the graph be smart enough to cull unnecessary secondary tests if `x` is huge? Because of the `logical_and`, in theory, it should be possible to discard warps/gpublocks that are testing the second conditional for elements that already failed the first test.